Screen flicking on Ubuntu 24.04
I am experiencing an issue with my Ubuntu where the bottom part of the screen is flickering.
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/aiiv2au1q6u6cot9tnkpn/f96b76eb340b6563e9d2ff987113cfae.mp4?rlkey=flab2edvqov20s3c1sn81lcyv&st=39oxf0jp&dl=0
I attempted to resolve the issue by modifying the /etc/default/grub, but it was unsuccessful.
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=igfx_off"
12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1250U
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble
Does anyone have any clues?
